# For Express Checkout, are you required to use the official paypal buttons for checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I keep reading everywhere that you are REQUIRED to use the (ugly) yellow buttons PayPal provides you with, yet when I go to `www.bustedtees.com` or `www.devtees.com` they use their own buttons that then link to the Express Checkout.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use our own buttons on our website and did not have any problems. Buttons are just recommended option for user recognition of familiar button

Answer (score 0):

There are no technical restrictions, and if you want to know if there are formal requirements from PayPal you would need to read their agreements. (Yes I know, reading clickthrough agreements -- who does that?) :). If you violate their terms of service they MIGHT come tell you to change your integration, but probably not.

HOWEVER, one thing to think about: familiar patterns "grease the rails" for users: increase recognition and you increase conversion. This means more people end up buying from you. Those distinctive (and yes, ugly) buttons help people recognize the PayPal checkout option and select it rather than potentially leaving your site because they didn't see a PayPal checkout option, or seeing a button labelled PayPal but being suspicious of it because it "didn't look right."

I know in my personal experience that I have been extremely frustrated trying to pay some sites with PayPal and have left & bought from other places because the checkout was non-obvious (especially when placed on the 35th page of a long checkout process, heh).

But this is backed up not just by personal experience, but market research. PayPal did some market research years ago and the #1 reason that paypal users failed to use PayPal checkout when it was available was that while the person may have seen a PayPal logo, they didn't recognize that they could pay on that site with PayPal because the checkout wasn't immediately familar to them. At that time this was with well-integrated sites that followed all of PayPal's guidelines BUT merchant-site PayPal checkout at that time looked a bit different than on eBay, which was the #1 site on which people pay with PayPal (and still is) -- including a different button.

The difference in conversion rate was STAGGERING, though. Like, more than half the people failed to pay with PayPal because the button was unfamiliar or placed in an unfamiliar location. So consider carefully whether or how much you want to leverage people's existing habits vs showing them something new.... your site may look less ugly but also sell less product.